# whoosh MultifieldParser field search or query parser concatenation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, filter, whoosh

I'm trying to use [whoosh](http://whoosh.ca/) to add search functionality to my blogapp on appengine but I don't understand some stuff.

The blogentries are indexed with `title`, `content` and `status` fields.

I would like to have different type of results on the public page then on the admin page but without the need to have multiple indexes.

On the frontpage I want visitors to be able to search on *visible* entries only on the `title` and `content` fields and in the admin I want to search also on *draft* entries.

Can i concatenate searches using `QueryParser` so I can search on multiple fields?
How could I filter on *status:visible* with `MultifieldParser`?

**EDIT**

didn't test it yet but i got an answer on the whoosh mailing list:

```
# Create a parser that will search in title and content
qp = qparser.MultifieldParser(["title", "content"], ix.schema)
# Parse the user query
q = qp.parse(user_query_string)
# If request is not admin, filter on status:visible
filterq = query.Term("status", u"visible") if not is_admin else None
# Get search results
results = searcher.search(q, filter=filterq)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not strictly an answer but Google added a full text search api similar to whoosh. Perhaps you should try it.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview

Comment: thx for the answer... i asked this question over a year ago :) a lot of stuff happened since then. i tried different approaches since then. right now i have an external server with elasticsearch.

Comment: ops sorry!!! it showed up first in stack overflow and i never noticed the date!! :)